# Git branch from old commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-branch-sculpting

I've researched this on SO and other documentation.   I've tried rebasing, merging, cherry-picking, and detached heads.

After literally 6 hours of trying to do this, it's time to ask the question!

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G master
```

Here's what I want to change it to:

```
A-B      F-G  master
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
```

The closest I've come is:

```
A-B      C-D-E-F-G-H Main
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
        \
         F-G master
```

I had to add another branch name and a dummy commit to get the branching to work at all.

But this is worse than no change.

Please help!

**UPDATE AFTER REPLIES**

Thanks for the replies.

Yes, my "what I want" was not very clear.  Hopefully this clarifies it:

```
A-B   -  F-G  master
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
```

In other words, "master" at F is the result of B plus branch "dev" merged into it.

**STILL NOT WORKING**

Thanks @frasertweedale for the attempted answer.

I've followed your instructions carefully and here's what I end up with:

```
A-B   -  "merge branch 'dev'"-G  master
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
        \ 
         F-G-"merge branch 'dev'"-F-G
```

I'm glad this is hard: having now spent 7 hours on this I don't feel as bad!

**FINAL RESULT**
As @frasertweedale said, this is exactly what I wanted except for the dangling commits.

So, I simply need to get rid of the dangles.

For clarity, I've redrawn below:

```
A-B   -  "merge branch 'dev'"-G2  master
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
        \ 
         F1-G1-"merge branch 'dev'"-F2-G2
```

And this command does the cleanup:

```
git rebase -p --onto F1^ F1
```

Result:

```
A-B   -  "merge branch 'dev'"-G2  master
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
```

"merge branch 'dev'" contains the original F commit, and can, of course, be re-commented that way.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "what I want" picture? Do you want to keep master as it is, and add a branch dev that is at commit E?

Comment: Based on your ASCII graphs, deleting `Main` would be enough to land you in the desired state... What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Jubobs Deleting Main would give me back the original picture, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you expand `A`, `B`, etc into their corresponding commit hashes, and that `master` is at `G`, the first step is to branch `dev` at `E`:

```
git branch dev E
```

Then reset `master` to `B`.

```
git reset --hard B
```

Next, merge `dev` into `master`, explicitly demanding a merge commit (it will otherwise do a *fast-forward* since  `dev` has not diverged from `master`):

```
git merge --no-ff dev
```

`master` now contains commits up to `E`.  Now you can *cherry-pick* the original `F` and `G` commits.

```
git cherry-pick F
git cherry-pick G
```

Now you have something very close to what you wanted; the only difference is the addition of a merge commit `(B+E)`:

```
A-B   -  (B+E)-F-G  master
   \    / 
    C-D-E dev
```

If you now want to include the content of `F` in the merge commit `(B+E)`, you can perform an *interactive rebase* and squash the two commits together.  The `--preserve-merges` (alias `-p`) option is essential.

```
git rebase --interactive --preserve-merges B
```

This will invoke an editor with content similar to the following (commit hashes and summaries will differ):

```
pick d4057bd c
pick 9419ef8 d
pick ad9e208 e
pick 120a90a Merge branch 'dev'
pick 61552ad f     
pick c947153 g
```

Replace the `pick` directive at the start of the `F` commit line with the `squash` directive (in the above example: `squash 61552ad f`), then save and exit.  You will be prompted to form a new commit message from the commit messages of the merge commit and `F`, and the rebase operation will then complete without further interation.  After the rebase, you will have *exactly* the repository history you asked for (in your updated question).

**ABBREVIATED SCRIPT**

The following script creates a new repository with a linear history, then automatically edits the history using (mostly) the same steps as above.  The interactive rebase is avoided so that user intervention is not required.

```
mkdir foo ; cd foo
git init
for C in A B C D E F G; do
    echo $C > $C
    git add $C
    git commit -m $C
    git tag $C
done
git branch dev E
git reset --hard B --
git merge --no-ff dev
git cherry-pick F
git reset --soft HEAD~
git commit --amend -m F
git cherry-pick G
for C in A B C D E F G; do
    git tag -d $C
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  When you say: "Replace the pick preceding the F commit with squash" do you mean that I should squash "pick 120a90a Merge branch 'dev'" in your example (replace "pick" with "squash")?  I tried that but get the error message "Refusing to squash a merge"

Comment: @russellr I mean "preceding" as in "immediately preceding" (on the same line).  I will clarify answer.  Thanks!

Comment: It does work.  I have added an abbreviate script that does the whole thing automatically (though it must avoid `rebase -i` so that user interaction is not required, so that part is *slightly* different).  But on closer inspection, your result which you claim is not correct does seem correct, except that the commit message of the merge commit (into which `F` was squashed) was left unchanged.  And of course you have some dangling objects in your repository, but with respect to the `dev` and `master` branches it appears to be correct, modulo merge commit message.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the result being the same as what I wanted, except for some dangling commits.  I did this to get rid of them: git rebase -p --onto F^ F.  Thanks so much!